# Неверная кодировка на хосте

Tags: apache, кодировка, веб-программирование

При тесте на апаче все норм, а вот на хосте русский текст в виде вопросительных знаков. Во что перекодировать?

Comment: У меня который год в подвале происходит подземный стук. Объясните, пожалуйста, как он происходит.

Comment: Я не знаю как звучит, но это так.На апаче работает,на хосте вместо текста - ????

Comment: @Jamper: это звучит так: "у меня есть проблема с кодировками, но разобраться в том, какую кодировку отдаёт сервер и в какой кодировке мой файл, я не умею или мне лениво, поэтому подскажите магическое заклинание, которое сразу сделает всё хорошо".

Answer (score 4):

мой ответ строится на том, что вы хотите указать кодировку `utf-8`.

1) ваш документ должен быть отредактирован под `UTF-8` без `BOM` (с этим хорошо справляется `Notepad++` (контекстное меню кодировки\преобразовать в UTF-8 без BOM))

2) если вас не устраивает кодировка выгрузки из БД

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

3) укажите кодировку в самом документе

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

4) есть ещё возможность настройки htacess и php.ini - но уверен, вам и без них будет "ютеэфно" =)

Comment: .htaccess:

    AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.Буду разбираться в чем проблема...

Answer (score 0):

Я использую UTF-8 без BOM и другим советую.
Так же я лично не использую данную строку:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

и тому подобные

Comment: а браузеру предлагаете догадываться, в какой кодировке ваш текст?

Comment: Часто тут такие вопросы=)
Ищите ответы в этой теме http://hashcode.ru/questions/181715/php-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5